# Trying to sort array of objects in descending order wrt to a key (name)and want the data with uppercase letters to show up first in vuejs

Tags: javascript, sorting, vuejs2, lodash

I am trying to sort an array of objects with reference to a key (name) and I want the data with uppercase to show first, but it is returning the data with lowercase letters first.
I am using lodash method, orderby 
The array retrieved is :

```
data = [
   {
      "id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000100000",
      "name":"DAS_Name_1",
      "layer":"Raw",
      "securityClass":"Green",
      "domainName":null,
      "domainId":null,
      "isActive":true,
      "isLocked":true,
      "creationDate":"2019-10-09T23:12:34Z",
      "createdByName":"DAS_Actor_User_Name_1",
      "createdById":"User_Id_1"
   },
   {
      "id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000100009",
      "name":"u_123",
      "layer":"Standardized",
      "securityClass":"Green",
      "domainName":null,
      "domainId":null,
      "isActive":true,
      "isLocked":true,
      "creationDate":"2019-10-09T23:12:34Z",
      "createdByName":"DAS_Actor_User_Name_10",
      "createdById":"User_Id_10"
   },
   {
      "id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000100099",
      "name":"Velvetica-123",
      "layer":"Standardized",
      "securityClass":"Red",
      "domainName":null,
      "domainId":null,
      "isActive":false,
      "isLocked":true,
      "creationDate":"2019-10-09T23:12:34Z",
      "createdByName":"DAS_Actor_User_Name_20",
      "createdById":"User_Id_20"
   },
   {
      "id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000100100",
      "name":"test_run-2",
      "layer":"Data_Products",
      "securityClass":"Green",
      "domainName":null,
      "domainId":null,
      "isActive":true,
      "isLocked":true,
      "creationDate":"2019-10-09T23:12:34Z",
      "createdByName":"DAS_Actor_User_Name_1",
      "createdById":"User_Id_1"
   }
]
```

While I sort the data array with lodash method:

```
data = _.orderBy(data, ["name"], ["desc"]);
```

But I get the result as follows:

```
data = [
   {
      "id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000100000",
      "name":"test_run-2",
      "layer":"Raw",
      "securityClass":"Green",
      "domainName":null,
      "domainId":null,
      "isActive":true,
      "isLocked":true,
      "creationDate":"2019-10-09T23:12:34Z",
      "createdByName":"DAS_Actor_User_Name_1",
      "createdById":"User_Id_1"
   },
   {
      "id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000100009",
      "name":"u_123 ",
      "layer":"Standardized",
      "securityClass":"Green",
      "domainName":null,
      "domainId":null,
      "isActive":true,
      "isLocked":true,
      "creationDate":"2019-10-09T23:12:34Z",
      "createdByName":"DAS_Actor_User_Name_10",
      "createdById":"User_Id_10"
   },
   {
      "id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000100099",
      "name":"Velvetica-123",
      "layer":"Standardized",
      "securityClass":"Red",
      "domainName":null,
      "domainId":null,
      "isActive":false,
      "isLocked":true,
      "creationDate":"2019-10-09T23:12:34Z",
      "createdByName":"DAS_Actor_User_Name_20",
      "createdById":"User_Id_20"
   },
   {
      "id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000100100",
      "name":"DAS_Name_1 ",
      "layer":"Data_Products",
      "securityClass":"Green",
      "domainName":null,
      "domainId":null,
      "isActive":true,
      "isLocked":true,
      "creationDate":"2019-10-09T23:12:34Z",
      "createdByName":"DAS_Actor_User_Name_1",
      "createdById":"User_Id_1"
   }
]
```

which is incorrect. Can someone suggest what to do here?

Comment: Please edit your question

Answer (score 1):

A simple ascending sort takes care of it.

As the ASCII value of "A" is 65 compared to the ASCII value of "a" which is 97.

So a simple ascending sort will be able to club all the Capitalised value to top of the array.

Tried it [here](https://repl.it/repls/SplendidGreenyellowPassword)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, comparing strings using `<` or `>` is case *sensitive* [[source]](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-comparison-operators/), which means you could simple use Javascript's native `Array.sort()` function [[documentation]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a < b) {
    return -1
  }

  if (a > b) {
    return 1
  }

  return 0
})
```